# export the gridview to excel sheet by clicking on submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I am creating a c# application.
In this application I take inputs from user and using those entries I fire a sql query and dispay the results in the Gridview.
So these actions happen when we click on submit button.
After this, I want to give the user an option to export the gridview results to an excel sheet by clicking on another submit button.
the code for these things is:

aspx code:

```
     <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <b>Enter Value 1 :</b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="p1" runat="server" />
                <br />

                <b>Enter value 2 :</b>
                <asp:TextBox ID="p2" runat="server" /><br />

                <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Start Search" />
                 <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Export Data to Excel" />
                <hr />

                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                            OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging"
                            ShowFooter="false"
                            CssClass="gridstyle"
                            EnableViewState="false"
                            AllowPaging="true">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrowstyle" />
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle" />
                            <RowStyle Wrap="false" />
                            <HeaderStyle Wrap="false" />
                        </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

The code file for this code is:

```
    public partial class pSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new  SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet dsldata;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds0 = new DataSet();
        ds0 = (DataSet)Session["data"]; 
        DataView dataview_ldata = dsldata.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        DataTable dt = dsldata.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSource = dataview_ldata;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        ExportToExcel(GridView1);

    }



    private void ExportToExcel(GridView GrdView)
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            // If you want the option to open the Excel file without saving than
            // comment out the line below
            // Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            GrdView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
        }
    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        string RName = Page.Request.QueryString["RName"];
        string typeofquery = "mycommand";
        string pv1 = p1.Text ;
        string pv2 = p2.Text ;
        string abc = null;
        abc = "" + typeofquery + " @RName=" + RName + ",@P1='" + pv1 + "',@P2='" + pv2 + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter cmdldata = new SqlDataAdapter(abc, sqlconn);

        GridView1.PageSize = 1000;


        cmdldata.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
         dsldata = new DataSet();
        ErrorHandling errhandle = new ErrorHandling();
        try
        {
            cmdldata.Fill(dsldata);
            Session["data"] = dsldata;

            DataView dataview_ldata = dsldata.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            DataTable dt = dsldata.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataSource = dataview_ldata;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }//end of try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String errorMessage = errhandle.displayException(ex);
            Response.Write(errorMessage);

        }//end of catch
        finally
        {
            if (errhandle != null)
            {
                errhandle = null;
            }
        }//end of finally
    }

      public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

        // Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET server control at run time.

    }

    protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    }
```

I am getting an empty excel sheet right now as my output.

From my anaysis I think the following is the problem:
When button 1 is clicked Gridview is generated by the query.When button 2 is clicked , all the data that It had previously is lost (even though we can still see it on the screen).That is why I am getting an empty excel sheet right now.

Secondly,Since I am creating the gridview on button click and not on the page load,the data of the gridview is not available in the 
     protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){} 
function.

Only option now to make it working is I should do the same operations of executing the query again on button2_Click function also.

But again I don't think this is an efficient way.And moreover I am running a complex query that may take 3 -4 mins at times to give the output.So running the query two times is out of question. I also tried caching the dataset but it did not work.Even creating session in not working.

I have been breaking my head on this since last 1 day. Please help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache sounds like a good solution, could you post your cache code?

Otherwise, I would do it in ViewState.  Get the result of your long query, store it in ViewState, bind the result to the GridView, then after your button click, you can access the ViewState-stored data.  This isn't the best way to do it for large sets of data, because ViewState is sent across the wire with each PostBack and stored on the client side.  It can really slow your application down and cause unexpected errors.

Here's my edit, that I got working locally:

Storing it in Session should work fine.  Here's what I did with some dummy data.  FYI, you can bind a `GridView` directly to a DataSet, you don't have to drill down to a DataTable or anything like that.

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string RName = Page.Request.QueryString["RName"];
            string typeofquery = "mycommand";
            string pv1 = p1.Text;
            string pv2 = p2.Text;
            string abc = null;
            abc = "" + typeofquery + " @RName=" + RName + ",@P1='" + pv1 + "',@P2='" + pv2 + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter cmdldata = new SqlDataAdapter(abc, sqlconn);

            GridView1.PageSize = 1000;


            cmdldata.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;

            var dummyDt = new DataTable();
            dummyDt.Columns.Add("Sup");
            dummyDt.Columns.Add("Bro");

            dummyDt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
            dummyDt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
            dummyDt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
            dummyDt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
            dummyDt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");

            dsldata = new DataSet();
            dsldata.Tables.Add(dummyDt);
            //ErrorHandling errhandle = new ErrorHandling();
            try
            {
                //cmdldata.Fill(dsldata);
                Session["data"] = dsldata;

                //DataView dataview_ldata = dsldata.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                //DataTable dt = dsldata.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataSource = dsldata;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }//end of try
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //String errorMessage = errhandle.displayException(ex);
                Response.Write(ex.Message);

            }//end of catch
            finally
            {
                //if (errhandle != null)
                //{
                //    errhandle = null;
                //}
            }//end of finally
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //DataSet ds0 = new DataSet();
            //ds0 = ;
            //DataView dataview_ldata = dsldata.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            //DataTable dt = dsldata.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataSource = (DataSet)Session["data"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            ExportToExcel(GridView1);

        }

        private void ExportToExcel(GridView GrdView)
        {
            try
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.xls");
                Response.Charset = "";
                // If you want the option to open the Excel file without saving than
                // comment out the line below
                // Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
                GrdView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
                Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: in my code above I have shown session.I have done caching in similar way.To cache the data set:  Cache["data"] = dsldata; and to access the cached dataset : ds0 = (DataSet)Cache["data"]; View state is also a good option for now.I will start working on it then.Will get back to you once I try that.Do let me know if you have any other solution.! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll tell you in the past I've used nearly the exact code to export to Excel, and have had no issue.  I've never had to re-bind the gridview, either.  Have you tried Button2_Click without any of the code before the call to `ExportToExcel`?

Comment: I tried using viewstate: so in the code (posted in the question above) i replaces Session with viewstate and now it is giving me Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error since the Viewstate was empty. Am I implementing it correctly?

Comment: yes I have tried that too.In my button2_click I directly call the ExportToExcel(Gridview1) function.But the output is empty excel sheet.

Comment: Looking through your code, in `ExportToExcel`, you refer to GrdView instead of GridView1 for your RenderHtml call.  Did you mistype something, or is there another `GridView` you are incorrectly rendering for?

Comment: That wont make any difference since when I call ExportToExcel(Gridview1) the function ExportToExcel(GridView GrdView) will take the passed value Gridview1 only.anyways to tried to take off the passed parameter and in button2_click I called ExportToExcel(); and changed the function to ExportToExcel().And directly access Gridview1 inside the code which is also giving me empty excelsheet

Comment: I gave up trying to fix it in my head and just did it locally and tested.  Edited my answer with a working solution using dummy data.

Comment: Yes it is working now!!!! Thank you soo much! But my whole page (the two text boxes ,the two submit buttons along with the gridview) is getting saved in excel sheet.Do you know any reason behind that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32521/discussion-between-aabbcc-and-garrison-neely)

Comment: Sorry, chat is blocked at work.  That's odd, because in my test version I'm only seeing the rendered GridView.  Did you modify your ExportToExcel in any way from the one I have above?

Comment: I am sorry I might have changed ExportToExcel. I just took your your and everything now is working in the expected way. A big thank you.I literally spent my whole day behind this code! Thank you again.